# How can I draw a custom ComboBox inside a DataGridViewCell?

Tags: .net, combobox, paint, datagridviewcolumn

I have a custom `ComboBox` control that I want to use in a `DataGridViewCell`. I first inherited `DataGridViewCell` and am trying to override the `Paint()` method to paint the `ComboBox` in the cell.

My problem is that after inheriting `DataGridViewColumn` and setting the `CellTemplate` property to a new instance of my `CustomDataGridViewCell` class, the cell is grey with no contents.

The `cBox` class variable is instantiated in the object ctor.

```
protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, 
   Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState, 
   object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, 
   DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle borderStyle,
   DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
{
   // Call MyBase.Paint() without passing object for formattedValue param
   base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value, 
       "", errorText, cellStyle, borderStyle, paintParts);
    
   // Set ComboBox properties
   this.cBox.CheckOnClick = true;
   this.cBox.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.Normal;
   this.cBox.DropDownHeight = 1;
   this.cBox.IntegralHeight = false;
   this.cBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(cellBounds.X, cellBounds.Y);
   this.cBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(cellBounds.Width, cellBounds.Height);
   this.cBox.ValueSeparator = ", ";
   this.cBox.Visible = true;
   this.cBox.Show();
}
```

How can I correctly paint the `ComboBox` in the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made fairly simple change that fixes my problem.

I had to correct the coordinates to be relative to the window instead of the `DataGridView`, call `Controls.Add()` for the owning form, and reposition the control in front of the `DataGridView`:

```
protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, 
   Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState, 
   object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, 
   DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle borderStyle, 
   DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
{
   // Just paint the border (because it shows outside the ComboBox bounds)
   this.PaintBorder(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, cellStyle, borderStyle);

   int cellX = this.DataGridView.Location.X + cellBounds.X;
   int cellY = this.DataGridView.Location.Y + cellBounds.Y;

   // Create ComboBox and set properties
   this.cBox = new CheckedComboBox();
   this.cBox.DropDownHeight = 1;
   this.cBox.IntegralHeight = false;
   this.cBox.Location = new Point(cellX, cellY);
   this.cBox.Size = new Size(cellBounds.Width, cellBounds.Height);
   this.cBox.ValueSeparator = ", ";
    
   // Add to form and position in front of DataGridView
   this.DataGridView.FindForm.Controls.Add(this.cBox);
   this.cBox.BringToFront();
}
```

Comment: Hi.Could you provide the files to have a CheckedCombBox inside DataGridView?